# с++: прекратить выполнение всех потоков

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, stl

Формирую задачу, которая будет выполняться в нескольких потоках с помощью stl следующим образом:

```
// подготовить данные
CTasksData tasksData;

// запустить потоки
std::mutex lock;
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

for (int threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < threadsAmount; threadIndex++)
{
    threads.push_back(std::thread(&taskFunc, std::ref(lock), &tasksData));
}

// дождаться завершения потоков
for (auto& thread : threads)
{
    if (thread.joinable())
        thread.join();
}
```

Подскажите как корректно сделать следующее:

как только один из потоков завершается, то и все остальные потоки (не важно на каком этапе они были) прекращают выполняться

Я реализовал это через специальный флаг в `CTasksData` и потоки постоянно проверяют, установлен ли он

```
for ()
{
    // проверка флага
    // основной функционал 
}
```

Недостаток такого подхода в том, что пока выполняется основной функционал, проверки не будет (хотя это и происходит быстро)

Да и когда я стал смотреть как загружены ядра, то у меня сложилось впечатление, что потоки как-то неохотно отпускаются.

Вот и хотелось бы, чтобы как только один из потоков прекращал выполнение, остальные сразу дохли бы... но корректно

Comment: ты всё правильно делаешь... единственное что — строго говоря, флаг должен быть `std::atomic`. Если есть сомнения по поводу скорости завершения потоков, то можешь замерить время между установкой флага и `join`'ом всех потоков...

Comment: Можно https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable прикрутить и всем говорить о прекращении

Comment: @Fat-Zer, о! Прочитал про атомики, очень подойдут для такого кода у меня: вместо `lock.lock(); const int threadIndex = tasksData->threadNew; tasksData->threadNew++; lock.unlock();` эффективнее наверное сделать так: `const int threadIndex = tasksData->threadNew.fetch_add(1);` P.S. до сих пор не пойму как в комментариях многострочный код добавлять

Comment: @Fat-Zer, просто думал, что есть способ, аналогичный `::TerminateThread`, который прибил бы потоки

Comment: Как же хочется где-нибудь большими красными буквами написать **потоки НЕЛЬЗЯ убивать насильно**, а если очень хочется, то всё равно нельзя... и только если ты понимаешь во всех подробностях, почему этого делать нельзя и все сложности, которые возникнут при __специальном__ написании кода потока таким образом, что его можно убить в любой точке, то только в этом абсурдном случае можно задуматься о том, чтобы нарушить это правило... и да, в стандартном с++, к счастью, ничего подобного нет — ИМХО это спасло значительное количество ног...

Comment: @Zhihar, по предыдущему: думаю ты имел ввиду `tasksData->threadNew.fetch_add(1)`, но учти, что на практике это может быть просто экономией на спичках... возможно, стоило бы раздать эти значения потокам при запуске... ЗЫ: а в комментарии многострочный код добавлять нельзя...

Comment: @Andrey, казалось бы, при чём здесь это?..

Comment: @Fat-Zer ????????????

Comment: @Andrey, с помощью CV можно заставить один или несколько потоков ждать какого-то события... в задаче OP'а её ни как на прикрутить...